# Check Box with title as json value

Tags: jquery, html, json

I have  added check box in jquery.jsoneditor.js file to select the  particular object. what my issue is 
if i have give the json value as title of the checkbox when i getting the title value it returns half of the json and not a full json
my json look like

```
{
  "id": "69553328633",
  "posts": {
    "data": [
      {
        "id": "69553328633_10151581128533634",
        "from": {
          "category": "Sports league",
          "category_list": [
            {
              "id": "1800",
              "name": "Sports League"
            }
          ],
          "name": "IPL - Indian Premier League",
          "id": "69553328633"
        },
        "story": "IPL - Indian Premier League added a new photo.",
        "story_tags": {
          "0": [
            {
              "id": "69553328633",
              "name": "IPL - Indian Premier League",
              "offset": 0,
              "length": 27,
              "type": "page"
            }
          ]
        },
        "picture": "https://fbcdn-photos-a-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash3/944546_10151581127693634_699916357_s.jpg",
        "link": "https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10151581127693634&set=a.10151581127568634.1073741865.69553328633&type=1&relevant_count=1",
        "name": "Here's wishing Ashoke Dinda and Sreyasi a very happy married life",
        "icon": "https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/rsrc.php/v2/yz/r/StEh3RhPvjk.gif",
        "actions": [
          {
            "name": "Comment",
            "link": "https://www.facebook.com/69553328633/posts/10151581128533634"
          },
          {
            "name": "Like",
            "link": "https://www.facebook.com/69553328633/posts/10151581128533634"
          }
        ],
        "privacy": {
          "value": ""
        },
        "type": "photo",
        "status_type": "added_photos",
        "object_id": "10151581127693634",
        "created_time": "2013-07-23T09:44:22+0000",
        "updated_time": "2013-07-23T09:44:22+0000",
        "shares": {
          "count": 52
        },
        "likes": {
          "data": [
            {
              "name": "Anwar Rasheed",
              "id": "100006402008184"
            },
            {
              "name": "Ankita Samanta",
              "id": "100002809625747"
            },
            {
              "name": "Akhil Raj",
              "id": "100003174377952"
            },
            {
              "name": "Naadir Mohamed",
              "id": "100002925781786"
            }
          ],
          "count": 737
        },
        "comments": {
          "data": [
            {
              "id": "10151581127693634_9415617",
              "from": {
                "name": "Santosh Bhiwandkar",
                "id": "650967778"
              },
              "message": "where is his headband ?",
              "can_remove": false,
              "created_time": "2013-07-23T09:53:08+0000",
              "like_count": 30,
              "user_likes": false
            },
            {
              "id": "10151581127693634_9415604",
              "from": {
                "name": "Aejaz Khan",
                "id": "100003171494760"
              },
              "message": "Yaha bhi place (seat) nahi mili dinda ko lolz :-P",
              "can_remove": false,
              "created_time": "2013-07-23T09:49:53+0000",
              "like_count": 22,
              "user_likes": false
            },
            {
              "id": "10151581127693634_9415862",
              "from": {
                "name": "Vallabh Shah",
                "id": "629812083"
              },
              "message": "Párth Shah Monil Salot Niyat Patel Kurven Desai Môhammed Aftab Šhethwala Priyal Mehta haha! keo cartoon lage che :-D",
              "message_tags": [
                {
                  "id": "692686557",
                  "name": "Párth Shah",
                  "type": "user",
                  "offset": 0,
                  "length": 10
                },
                {
                  "id": "100000063761663",
                  "name": "Monil Salot",
                  "type": "user",
                  "offset": 11,
                  "length": 11
                },
                {
                  "id": "617467712",
                  "name": "Niyat Patel",
                  "type": "user",
                  "offset": 23,
                  "length": 11
                },
                {
                  "id": "621833052",
                  "name": "Kurven Desai",
                  "type": "user",
                  "offset": 35,
                  "length": 12
                },
                {
                  "id": "1112702217",
                  "name": "Môhammed Aftab Šhethwala",
                  "type": "user",
                  "offset": 48,
                  "length": 24
                },
                {
                  "id": "598974156",
                  "name": "Priyal Mehta",
                  "type": "user",
                  "offset": 74,
                  "length": 12
                }
              ],
              "can_remove": false,
              "created_time": "2013-07-23T11:12:37+0000",
              "like_count": 5,
              "user_likes": false
            },
            {
              "id": "10151581127693634_9415792",
              "from": {
                "name": "Sinchan Dutta",
                "id": "100002128277335"
              },
              "message": "langoor ko mil gaya angoor...........",
              "can_remove": false,
              "created_time": "2013-07-23T10:46:33+0000",
              "like_count": 4,
              "user_likes": false
            },
            {
              "id": "10151581127693634_9417467",
              "from": {
                "name": "Dipayan Sen",
                "id": "100000143868990"
              },
              "message": "sala bhikary ko mast maal milgaya,, asli IPL toh ab hoga iske liya..",
              "can_remove": false,
              "created_time": "2013-07-23T16:52:16+0000",
              "like_count": 2,
              "user_likes": false
            },
            {
              "id": "10151581127693634_9415651",
              "from": {
                "name": "Kapil Kumar",
                "id": "100001272757610"
              },
              "message": "congratulation...",
              "can_remove": false,
              "created_time": "2013-07-23T10:04:01+0000",
              "like_count": 0,
              "user_likes": false
            },
            {
              "id": "10151581127693634_9420063",
              "from": {
                "name": "Tara Prasad Panigrahi",
                "id": "100000244432604"
              },
              "message": "blwling mat bhul jana be",
              "can_remove": false,
              "created_time": "2013-07-24T00:56:58+0000",
              "like_count": 1,
              "user_likes": false
            },
            {
              "id": "10151581127693634_9420061",
              "from": {
                "name": "Tara Prasad Panigrahi",
                "id": "100000244432604"
              },
              "message": "ball ko thik se pakad na",
              "can_remove": false,
              "created_time": "2013-07-24T00:56:42+0000",
              "like_count": 1,
              "user_likes": false
            },
            {
              "id": "10151581127693634_9417270",
              "from": {
                "name": "Vishal Babbar",
                "id": "100000692501270"
              },
              "message": "Chess board",
              "can_remove": false,
              "created_time": "2013-07-23T16:15:07+0000",
              "like_count": 1,
              "user_likes": false
            },
            {
              "id": "10151581127693634_9417158",
              "from": {
                "name": "Anurag Sharma",
                "id": "1318817376"
              },
              "message": "abey DINDA ko ye kaise mil gai?",
              "can_remove": false,
              "created_time": "2013-07-23T15:59:17+0000",
              "like_count": 0,
              "user_likes": false
            },
            {
              "id": "10151581127693634_9416899",
              "from": {
                "name": "Shonali Iris Sinha",
                "id": "1704352717"
              },
              "message": "god bless :)",
              "can_remove": false,
              "created_time": "2013-07-23T15:09:45+0000",
              "like_count": 0,
              "user_likes": false
            },
            {
              "id": "10151581127693634_9416399",
              "from": {
                "name": "Ayaz Khan",
                "id": "100003804345041"
              },
              "message": "paisa bolta haiN",
              "can_remove": false,
              "created_time": "2013-07-23T13:18:33+0000",
              "like_count": 1,
              "user_likes": false
            },
            {
              "id": "10151581127693634_9415720",
              "from": {
                "name": "Abhik Sarkar",
                "id": "595475285"
              },
              "message": "CONGRATS...",
              "can_remove": false,
              "created_time": "2013-07-23T10:20:27+0000",
              "like_count": 1,
              "user_likes": false
            },
            {
              "id": "10151581127693634_9415716",
              "from": {
                "name": "Amit Bansal Agarwal",
                "id": "1678252827"
              },
              "message": "Chootiya",
              "can_remove": false,
              "created_time": "2013-07-23T10:19:43+0000",
              "like_count": 1,
              "user_likes": false
            },
            {
              "id": "10151581127693634_9435721",
              "from": {
                "name": "Rahmath Shah",
                "id": "100004637742739"
              },
              "message": "Congratulation dinda",
              "can_remove": false,
              "created_time": "2013-07-26T17:17:45+0000",
              "like_count": 0,
              "user_likes": false
            },
            {
              "id": "10151581127693634_9421568",
              "from": {
                "name": "Pratap Bera",
                "id": "100004569704353"
              },
              "message": "Wish you happy maried life.",
              "can_remove": false,
              "created_time": "2013-07-24T07:03:48+0000",
              "like_count": 0,
              "user_likes": false
            },
            {
              "id": "10151581127693634_9420549",
              "from": {
                "name": "Arsalan Khan",
                "id": "100003179656502"
              },
              "message": "betwa be miljai ga",
              "can_remove": false,
              "created_time": "2013-07-24T02:27:02+0000",
              "like_count": 0,
              "user_likes": false
            },
            {
              "id": "10151581127693634_9419086",
              "from": {
                "name": "Mahendrasingh Chauhan",
                "id": "100001153148424"
              },
              "message": "Happy Married Life, we indians r proud of u.",
              "can_remove": false,
              "created_time": "2013-07-23T21:37:26+0000",
              "like_count": 0,
              "user_likes": false
            },
            {
              "id": "10151581127693634_9418759",
              "from": {
                "name": "Mohammed Salimbahleem",
                "id": "592799594"
              },
              "message": "enjoy your life with fast ball",
              "can_remove": false,
              "created_time": "2013-07-23T20:49:10+0000",
              "like_count": 0,
              "user_likes": false
            },
            {
              "id": "10151581127693634_9418756",
              "from": {
                "name": "Mohammed Salimbahleem",
                "id": "592799594"
              },
              "message": "congrates to dinda and sreyasi",
              "can_remove": false,
              "created_time": "2013-07-23T20:48:55+0000",
              "like_count": 0,
              "user_likes": false
            },
            {
              "id": "10151581127693634_9418401",
              "from": {
                "name": "Umair Mithani",
                "id": "649484686"
              },
              "message": "bandar",
              "can_remove": false,
              "created_time": "2013-07-23T19:49:14+0000",
              "like_count": 0,
              "user_likes": false
            },
            {
              "id": "10151581127693634_9417640",
              "from": {
                "name": "Ajit Yadav",
                "id": "100001037242667"
              },
              "message": "wish u happy marriied life dinda ",
              "can_remove": false,
              "created_time": "2013-07-23T17:20:29+0000",
              "like_count": 0,
              "user_likes": false
            },
            {
              "id": "10151581127693634_9417630",
              "from": {
                "name": "Shashank Shrivastava",
                "id": "100004707751080"
              },
              "message": "Happy meried life",
              "can_remove": false,
              "created_time": "2013-07-23T17:19:29+0000",
              "like_count": 0,
              "user_likes": false
            },
            {
              "id": "10151581127693634_9417450",
              "from": {
                "name": "Pal Arabinda",
                "id": "100005542332515"
              },
              "message": "Pesh dadar pesi bou",
              "can_remove": false,
              "created_time": "2013-07-23T16:49:32+0000",
              "like_count": 0,
              "user_likes": false
            },
            {
              "id": "10151581127693634_9416828",
              "from": {
                "name": "Sehwag Dinesh",
                "id": "100000886889193"
              },
              "message": "happy married life dude",
              "can_remove": false,
              "created_time": "2013-07-23T14:56:40+0000",
              "like_count": 0,
              "user_likes": false
            }
          ],
          "paging": {
            "cursors": {
              "after": "NDE=",
              "before": "Njk="
            },
            "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/69553328633_10151581128533634/comments?limit=25&after=NDE="
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "paging": {
      "previous": "https://graph.facebook.com/69553328633/posts?limit=1&since=1374572662",
      "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/69553328633/posts?limit=1&until=1374572661"
    }
  }
}
```

How would i add  large json value as checkbox title. It is working perfect for smalll amount of josn 
if the json value is large only it has problem how would get the valid json from checkbox title

Comment: Do you want this entire JSON string to be the title for your checkbox?

Comment: @jackyesind, dude, could you please add your code in jsfiddle.net

Comment: Also, I think you should sanitize this data before posting it to a public website like StackOverflow. There are people's names and links to their pictures here...

Comment: @cfs yes because i want to save those json

Comment: @SAM the example shown in http://jsonmate.com/. I want to select one of the particular object and have to save the json which is in orange color